# Can Beast Boy change sex?

Tags: dc, teen-titans, beast-boy

There are several animal species that have the ability to change sex under certain conditions, for example, the clown fish. If Beast Boy were to change into a clown fish (or another sex changing animal) would he be able to change sex as well? Has he ever been shown to do this?

Comment: I've replaced references to "gender" with "sex" in your question, as you seem to be interested in whether he can change his reproductive anatomy, rather than whether he's [genderfluid](http://gender.wikia.com/wiki/Gender_Fluid) or whether he capable of becoming transgender.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish That was my intent though I'd be interested in knowing the answers to those as well.

Comment: More so than a sex-changing animal, I'd be interested to know if he can change an animal with large differences between sexes (e.g. male and female deer with or without horns).

Comment: [In Teen Titans Go, he turns into a female cow](https://youtu.be/3vaYJ6vCsi8) (also, what in the world did I just watch...)

Comment: We try not to talk about Teen Titans Go.

Comment: @Irishpanda Trust me, if I had found anything else I would have used it instead. This was all I could find...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Depending on if you consider it canon, *Teen Titans Go* has a scene wherein Beast Boy turns into a female cow, udder and all.

If canon then yes. But honestly, if the scene is any indication, the show is a mess...

Comment: It *is* a mess. They took a great show, lobotomized it, then filled it full of fart jokes. So sad, considering how good its predecessor was.

Answer (score 5):

While he has never been shown to do so, the nature of his powers *should* allow it.

He has shifted into forms of creatures that don't even exist in the past, and Marv Wolfman has even stated in an interview that his powers should allow him to shift into other humans. There is nothing to indicate that this would be limited by biological sex. He can also shift into the form of creatures that have no sexual dimorphism (such as a parasitic worm).

As a male, he most likely changes into male animals reflexively, but could shift into a female form (or other sex if he shifts into an alien species with more than two) with some extra thought and effort.